# simplexml_load_file with a parameter error

Tags: php, xml

I use this sample code to load an xml file

```
$XmlFile = "01022021.xml";
$file = "http://localhost/xml/xml/" . $XmlFile;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

but it doesn't work. I must use parametric load for the  `simplexml_load_file()`

If I use:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://localhost/xml/xml/01022021.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

it works.

Comment: It seems to run well from my side. Review your original code again searching for typos.

Comment: I think that a library isn't installed. The file is http://web.ct.ingv.it/xml/xml/01022021.xml, but it not load

Comment: The file that you said do not exists. It returns a 404 error: `404 - Impossibile trovare il file o la directory.`, so for that reason the function is not able to run well (at least now, no idea if yesterday that file existed).